# Is there a way to access jQuery object from previous chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure how I could search for these type of question/answer...

This is what I am trying to do...

```
(function($){
    $.fn.helloworld = {
        want: function () {
            alert("I want" + this + "!");
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now when I call the function this way, and try to retrieve `this`, it will only give me the `helloworld` "object".

```
$("#test").helloworld.want();
```

Is there a way to access the caller element, `#test`, from within?

Answer (score 4):

There's no "nice" way.  You could do this:

```
var $test = $('#test');
$test.helloworld.want.call($test);
```

The problem is that by setting up the structure you've got you're essentially forcing the behavior you say you don't want.

What you could do instead is this:

```
$.fn.helloworld = function( action ) {
  var actions = {
    test: function() {
      alert("Hi!");
    },
    // ...
  };

  if (actions[action])
    return actions[action].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
  return this;
};
```

Now you can call it:

```
$('#this').helloworld("test");
```

Comment: How about this? Is it possible to create a wrapper object that wraps around the jQuery object? So i have my own function that sits above jQuery, and when I need to call something, I can "inherit" the jQuery functionality by passing it along?

For example, $helloworld("#test").test(); When reality, my custom object becomes `$helloworld`, kind a similar to jQuery's `$` or `jQuery`.

Comment: @codenamezero You could use `$helloworld = Object.create($.prototype);` to create an object with the jQuery prototype. Of course, you won't pick up the functions like `$.get()` directly on the object, but you could copy those too. I don't see the point, though; you still have to share the same namespace with all the other jQuery functions.